# Putting 2 tables together

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\title{Untitled Document}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{xxx (ML2)}
\label{tab:4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|l}|}  \hline
\diagbox[width=10em]{given}{predicted}&
    1 & 0               \\ \hline
    1 & (TP) & (FN)  \\ \hline
    0 & (FP) & (TN)     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{yyy (Alg1)}
\label{tab:3}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|l}|}  \hline
\diagbox[width=10em]{given}{predicted}&
    1 & 0               \\ \hline
    1 & (TP) & (FN)  \\ \hline
    0 & (FP) & (TN)     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can I include both tables in one table. I'm going to submit a paper with only 4 pages and therefore I have to save space. Thank you in advance for your support. Cheers

Comment: delete `\end{table}

\begin{table}[!ht]`  from the middle of your example

Answer (score 3):

You place the tables in `minipages` in the same `table` environment, so they're typeset side by side.

However, in their current status the tables are too wide and difficult to read, so I present your original attempt and mine. Take your pick (and never again use `\diagbox`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\title{Untitled Document}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{table}[!htp]

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{xxx (ML2)}
\label{tab:4}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
given & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{predicted} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
& 1 & 0           \\
\midrule
 1 & (TP) & (FN) \\
 0 & (FP) & (TN) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{yyy (Alg1)}
\label{tab:3}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|l}|}  \hline
\diagbox[width=10em]{given}{predicted}&
    1 & 0               \\ \hline
    1 & (TP) & (FN)  \\ \hline
    0 & (FP) & (TN)     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the actual tables have different heights, you may want to use

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
```

and, if they also have different widths you may need to adjust the proportion in the width of the `minipage`s.

Answer (score 1):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Untitled Document}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\caption{xxx (ML2)}
\label{tab:4}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|l}|}
\hline
\diagbox[width=9em]{given}{predicted} &
1                                     & 0    \\ \hline
1                                     & (TP) &  (FN)   \\ \hline
0                                     & (FP) &  (TN)   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\caption{yyy (Alg1)}
\label{tab:3}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|l}|}
\hline
\diagbox[width=9em]{given}{predicted} &
1                                     & 0    \\ \hline
1                                     & (TP) &  (FN)   \\ \hline
0                                     & (FP) &  (TN)   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `floatrow`  package for that:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{diagbox}
    \usepackage{floatrow}
    \title{Untitled Document}
    \author{Your Name}
    \date{\today}

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{floatrow}
    \ttabbox{\caption{xxx (ML2)}
    \label{tab:4}}
    {\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|l}|} \hline
    \diagbox[width=10em]{given}{predicted}&
        1 & 0 \\ \hline
        1 & (TP) & (FN) \\ \hline
        0 & (FP) & (TN) \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    %
    \ttabbox{\caption{yyy (Alg1)}\label{tab:3}}
    {\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|l}|} \hline
    \diagbox[width=10em]{given}{predicted}&
        1 & 0 \\ \hline
        1 & (TP) & (FN) \\ \hline
        0 & (FP) & (TN) \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    \end{floatrow}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can have them equally distributed over the page width. While `minipage`s are to keep captions and tables together, each `minipage` can be placed side by side. Then, `\hspace{\fill}` is used as a filler adding required white space between tables and margins.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand*{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
  \renewcommand*{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{blue}}
\title{Untitled Document}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \hspace{\fill}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{xxx (ML2)}\label{tab:4}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|*2{X|}}
      \hline
      \diagbox[width=6em]{given}{pred.} & 1 & 0 \\
      \hline
      1 & (TP) & (FN)  \\ \hline
      0 & (FP) & (TN)     \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hspace{\fill}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{yyy (Alg1)}\label{tab:3}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|*2{X|}}  \hline
    \diagbox[width=6em]{given}{pred.}&
    1 & 0               \\ \hline
    1 & (TP) & (FN)  \\ \hline
    0 & (FP) & (TN)     \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hspace*{\fill}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me !! You guys are amazing ...